# Set element ID on page load with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, set, attr, pageload, document-ready

Assume that I have some HTML elements like these:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Parent 1</a>
            <ul>
                 <li><a>Child 1</a></li>
                 <li><a>Child 2</a></li>
                 <li><a>Child 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Parent 2</a>
            <ul>
                 <li><a>Child 1</a></li>
                 <li><a>Child 2</a></li>
                 <li><a>Child 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I set the ID for the first UL element in the #wrapper when $(document) ready??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `:first` like

```
$('#wrapper ul:first').attr('id', 'customeId');
```

Or you can try with `:eq(0)` like

```
$('#wrapper ul:eq(0)').attr('id', 'customeId');
```

Even(May be) you can try with `.eq(0)` like

```
$('#wrapper ul').eq(0).attr('id', 'customeId');
```

Make sure that you have this script on `DOM` ready like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper ul:first').attr('id', 'customeId');
});
```

And please correct your html because it is breaking while closing `ul`

Answer (score 2):

Like this.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gk7h5/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper ul:first').attr('id', 'yourid');
});
```

You have invalid html as well, you missed the closing ul

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Parent 1</a>
            <ul>
                 <li><a>Child 1</a></li>
                 <li><a>Child 2</a></li>
                 <li><a>Child 3</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </li>
        <li><a>Parent 2</a>
            <ul>
                 <li><a>Child 1</a></li>
                 <li><a>Child 2</a></li>
                 <li><a>Child 3</a></li>
            </ul>     
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wrapper").children("ul").attr("id", "myid");
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("#wrapper ul:first").attr("id","id");
```